# Is overprovisioning bad practice for preallocating C arrays?

Tags: c, arrays

I'm working on writing an interface from Python to C and the data structure in C is an array of the size of some variables. Since the size is not a constant before initializing the array, I don't know the length of the array.

Is making the array size 1000, where the size may be anywhere between 1 and 1000 — is it a bad practice? 
What would be a better way to do this? malloc?

Context: this pointer for the array will be used for sending over network as application layer protocol, so I need the data as an array.

Comment: No. It is an OK practice. There are pros and cons in static allocation vs dynamic one. You should evaluate them. And no, it is not an opinion based question, the answer is pretty objective if given the full information.

Comment: Sounds like you want a variable length array (which C has had since C99).

Comment: I recommend `alloca`

Comment: It depends on a number of things that you don't tell us about. For instance: Is memory usage important, is performance important, do you know an upper limit for number of elements and so on.

Answer (score 6):

It's only a bad practice if allocating 1000 elements is going to stress the memory available on the platform.  With just 1000 elements, that's seldom going to be a problem on servers or desktop machines; it might be a problem in embedded systems.  If you're looking at pre-allocating 1M or more elements, especially if the normal case will be 1k elements, then that is probably an overkill, even on big machines, though that's not completely clear-cut.  Stack size is limited, but global variables can often be huge.

What is the fallback plan if it turns out there are 1001 items to be processed?  Are your tests going to verify the behaviour when there are more rows?  Ignoring the problem isn't acceptable — it can cause buffer  or array overflows.  If you revert to dynamic allocation, maybe you should have been dynamically allocating all along (at least that way you know the dynamic memory allocation code is tested).  If you're simply going to reject extra elements and that will be OK to users, then you can simply use the fixed size and check that you don't overflow it.

Comment: I'll say that if the process **must** handle 1000-byte arrays and using 1000-byte arrays does stress the memory available on the system, the system is under-spec'd.

Comment: @andrew Henle: If you are designing for average need vs peak need and only need to handle 100 elements most of the time you could be okay. Altough malloc creates quite some overhead too, depending on your enviroment and we are talking about a order of 10 for average vs peak case (which is not much)...